# Program 'nvcc' is not found in $PATH

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, cuda, nvcc, nsight

and also getting 4x Error launching external scanner info generator(nvcc -dryrun -G -g -O0 .....)

I installed cuda toolkit 5 for ubuntu 12.04 and also installed dev drivers 
got gtx580

Comment: What is your question? If it isn't in your PATH, why don't you just add it?

Comment: Is this your first time installing cuda?  It sounds like it might be.  I have the cuda 5 kit installed on ubuntu.  Be sure to follow the directions to the letter.

Comment: Where do you I need to add the PATH? Do you mean the path of nvcc bin file  that is located in same directory as nsight launcher?

Answer (score 1):

How do you launch nsight? To launch Nsight you need to execute /usr/local/cuda/bin/nsight from the properly configures shell (the one that has nvcc on the $PATH

Final toolkit has fixed start-up script that updates PATH.

Comment: I edited the PATH to /usr/local/cuda/bin , but now I am getting this error:Invalid project path: Include path not found (/usr/local/cuda/include/cudart).

Comment: This is not an error, you can ignore it. You will not see this message in CUDA 5.0 release.

Comment: Note that that path is specified in nvcc.profile file in your toolkit install location. Feel free to remove it from that file.

Comment: okay! thank you Eugene , Carlos and talonmies for your help! You helped alot